# Android: my application will crash every time on the first time the application is open, and I can't set my message application as default

Tags: android, sms, message

I am trying to make my application as the default messaging application, hence the first time the application is open I will prompt the user if they want to make the application as the default application. If yes, it will change my application becomes the default. But now, whenever I first time open the application it will always crash. Can anyone guide me please. Since it always crash on the first time the application is open, the dialog box to prompt for the change of default application will not be shown, and hence my application can never becomes the default application.

Logcat:

```
08-03 14:43:09.498 816-816/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1686 com.android.server.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerService$DirectAccessBrocastReceiver.onReceive:383 android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run:923 android.os.Handler.handleCallback:739 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:95 
08-03 14:43:10.448 816-1061/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1686 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.notifyToSSRM:5628 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.access$600:192 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager$PolicyHandler.handleMessage:811 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:102 
08-03 14:43:11.978 816-1061/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1686 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.notifyToSSRM:5628 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.access$600:192 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager$PolicyHandler.handleMessage:811 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:102 
08-03 14:43:14.388 816-1061/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1686 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.notifyToSSRM:5628 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.access$600:192 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager$PolicyHandler.handleMessage:811 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:102 
08-03 14:43:15.008 816-1061/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1686 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.notifyToSSRM:5628 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.access$600:192 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager$PolicyHandler.handleMessage:811 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:102 
08-03 14:43:18.398 4316-4316/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1525)
08-03 14:43:18.398 4316-4316/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-03 14:43:19.178 816-1256/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.android.mms for broadcast com.android.mms/.freemessage.FreeMessageReceiver: pid=8209 uid=10053 gids={50053, 9997, 3003, 1028, 1015, 1023, 1003} abi=armeabi-v7a
08-03 14:43:19.528 8209-8209/? D/Mms/MmsConfig: setFreeMessageEnabled, getSupportedFeatures = -1 isAuth = false
08-03 14:43:19.558 8209-8209/? E/Mms/MessageUtils: setCountryDetector : update country detector info 
08-03 14:43:19.558 8209-8209/? E/Mms/MessageUtils: updateCountryIso : update country iso info 
08-03 14:43:19.658 1415-1653/? D/TP/MmsSmsProvider: delete URI_CONVERSATIONS_MESSAGES affectedRows=0
08-03 14:43:19.708 8209-8209/? D/Mms/MessagingNotification: [start]    init() consume time = 39.299062
08-03 14:43:19.708 8209-8209/? D/Mms/MessagingNotification: [end]    init consume time = 2.640261
08-03 14:43:19.728 8209-8209/? D/Mms/FreeMessageReceiver: onReceive, action : android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
08-03 14:43:19.758 8209-8233/? D/Mms/FreeMessageReceiverService: onHandleIntent, action : android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
08-03 14:43:19.758 8209-8233/? D/Mms/FreeMessageReceiverService: onHandleIntent: ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED
08-03 14:43:19.798 8209-8231/? D/Mms/MessagingNotification: checkBadgeCount unreadCount=1 badgeCount=1
08-03 14:43:19.938 8209-8231/? I/Mms/ReservationManager: getReservedSendMessageCount(): retMessageCount=0
08-03 14:43:20.868 816-1322/? D/SecContentProvider2: uri = 15 selection = getSealedHideNotificationMessages
08-03 14:43:20.868 8291-8291/? I/PopupuiReceiver_KNOX: getSealedHideNotificationMessages : 1
08-03 14:43:21.558 816-1463/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service flipboard.app/flipboard.remoteservice.MessengerService in 1000ms
08-03 14:43:21.748 8209-8209/? D/Mms/ComposeMessageFragment: [start]    fillCache consume time = 1972.000208
08-03 14:43:21.748 8209-8209/? D/Mms/ComposeMessageFragment: fillCache, easy = false
08-03 14:43:21.898 8209-8209/? D/Mms/ComposeMessageFragment: [end]    fillCache consume time = 147.638385
08-03 14:43:21.908 1101-1101/? I/TZ: qc_tlc_communication: max_message_size = 38912 = 0x9800
08-03 14:43:22.648 816-1045/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc flipboard.app for service flipboard.app/flipboard.remoteservice.MessengerService: pid=8448 uid=10124 gids={50124, 9997, 3003, 1028, 1015} abi=armeabi-v7a
08-03 14:43:23.158 8417-8433/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1686 android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast:391 com.samsung.android.app.filterinstaller.FilterUninstaller.uninstallFilters:44 com.samsung.android.app.filterinstaller.FilterPackageService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage:149 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:102 
08-03 14:43:23.268 5327-5327/? E/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.wear.bo.a(837): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
08-03 14:43:28.828 816-1099/? D/TimaService: TimaServiceHandler.handleMessage what =1
08-03 14:43:35.998 816-1060/? D/UsbDeviceManager: handleMessage -> MSG_POWER_STATE = 1
08-03 14:43:36.028 816-816/? I/CAE: handleMessage(CaPowerManager.java:193) - POWER_CONNECTED
08-03 14:43:36.058 816-1423/? D/SecContentProvider2: uri = 15 selection = getSealedHideNotificationMessages
08-03 14:43:36.058 8291-8291/? I/PopupuiReceiver_KNOX: getSealedHideNotificationMessages : 1
08-03 14:43:36.458 816-1060/? D/UsbDeviceManager: handleMessage -> MSG_UPDATE_STATE connected = 1,configured = 0
08-03 14:43:36.658 816-1060/? D/UsbDeviceManager: handleMessage -> MSG_UPDATE_STATE connected = 1,configured = 1
08-03 14:43:39.188 9080-9116/? E/MtpService: handleMessage. msg= { when=0 what=0 arg1=1 obj=Intent { cmp=com.samsung.android.MtpApplication/.MtpService } target=com.samsung.android.MtpApplication.MtpService$ServiceHandler }
08-03 14:43:39.228 9080-9080/? E/MTPJNIInterface: noti = 2

                                                  [ 08-03 14:43:39.228  9080: 9080 D/         ]
                                                  deleting sockets before message queue initialization


                                                  [ 08-03 14:43:39.228  9080: 9080 D/         ]
                                                  event handler thread is created, so set the flag
08-03 14:43:39.248 9080-9116/? E/MtpService: handleMessage. msg= { when=-4ms what=0 arg1=2 obj=Intent { cmp=com.samsung.android.MtpApplication/.MtpService } target=com.samsung.android.MtpApplication.MtpService$ServiceHandler }
08-03 14:43:42.198 9080-9080/? E/MTPRx: Open session has come  remove the  Message false
08-03 14:43:42.208 9080-9080/? E/MTPRx: Open session has come  remove the  Message false
08-03 14:46:22.068 816-1069/? D/PackageManager: remove MCS_UNBIND message and Posting MCS_UNBIND 10 secs later
08-03 14:46:22.108 816-816/? D/PackageManager: [VERIFY] sendMessageDelayed(CHECK_PENDING_VERIFICATION, 11, 10000)
08-03 14:46:24.278 816-816/? D/PackageManager: [VERIFY] sendMessageDelayed(CHECK_PENDING_VERIFICATION, 11, 10000)
08-03 14:46:27.058 4316-4316/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1525)
08-03 14:46:27.058 4316-4316/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-03 14:46:28.698 816-4077/? W/ActivityManager: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.apple.qs/.Activity.Activity.ActivityMain_txt } from null (pid=10272, uid=2000) requires android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE
08-03 14:46:29.378 10341-10341/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1509)
08-03 14:46:29.378 10341-10341/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-03 14:46:30.098 10374-10374/? D/Mms/MmsConfig: setFreeMessageEnabled, getSupportedFeatures = -1 isAuth = false
```

The code I set the app as default app:

```
 protected void onResume() {


        super.onResume();

        if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("pref_", true)) {
            //You can perform anything over here. This will call only first time
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

                if (!Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(this).equals(myPackageName)) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityMain_txt.this);
                    builder.setMessage("This app is not set as your default messaging app. Do you want to set it as default?")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setTitle("Alert!")
                            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            })

                            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @TargetApi(19)
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
                                    intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, getPackageName());

                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    // ActivityMain_txt.this.finish();


                                }

                            });
                    builder.show();

                }


            }


            editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("pref_", false);
            editor.commit();

        }


    }
```

Manifest:

```
  <activity android:name=".Activity.ActivityMain_txt" android:enabled="@bool/is_kitkat"  android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE">
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android-dir/mms-sms" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".receiver.HeadlessSmsSendService"
            android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.ActivityMessageDetails_txt"
            android:label="List" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.ActivityNewMessage_txt"
            android:label="New Message" >
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".receiver.MessageReceiver" android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="receiver.MmsReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Shared Preference:

```
public static boolean getBooleanPref(String key_val, boolean def_val, Context context) {
        SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("pref_"+key_val,context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return pref.getBoolean(key_val, def_val);
    }

    public static void setBooleanPref(String key_val, boolean val, Context context) {
        SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("pref_"+key_val,context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = pref.edit();
        prefEditor.clear();
        prefEditor.putBoolean(key_val, val);
        prefEditor.commit();
    }
```

Comment: Please post your logcat directly on StackOverflow.

Comment: Ok. I have edited and copy part of the logcat on top. Thanks.